# How to detect row group name on filter change?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have columns that they are group by some section name.
Now i need to recognize which column belongs to what section.
When i use `let filter = gridApi.getFilterModel();` im getting only what filter is changed, but i want to know which group it belongs to.

[image]

For example if i want to search country it belongs to athlete details, and on filter change i need that information.

Any suggestion?

Comment: can u create a stackblitz demo ?

Comment: Can you show some of your relevent code too ?